# kswapd0 in ubuntu slows down the system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, proc, top

We don't have any service running in the ubuntu but currently, we see the system becomes very slow from the morning,

When I tried `top` command, I see there are  two new services running like below,

```
top - 11:34:11 up 14 days,  4:27,  2 users,  load average: 196.25, 196.95, 205.08
Tasks: 138 total,   2 running,  77 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 42.3 us,  2.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi, 55.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8125684 total,  5043148 free,  2952856 used,   129680 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  4967508 avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
127090 test      20   0 2432756 2.287g   1508 S 200.0 29.5 615:13.56 kswapd0
 31462 test      20   0 5261204  74492   3272 S 200.0  0.9 132:10.43 tsm
```

Additional information :

```
 free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7935        2887        4924           0         124        4848
Swap:             0           0           0
```

which takes too much of CPU and now I am not able to perform any command in the system,
Does anyone face this issue?

I already tried this : `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` but no luck,

Anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Linux workstation is infected with some malware, most likely some cryptominer.

In reality `kswapd0` must always be a kernel/root process using *zero VIRT/RES/SHR resources (because the kernel doesn't account its own usage in kernel threads)* while your "kswapd0" is running under your user account.

I recommend that you reinstall everything from scratch (while wiping clean the entire disk, e.g. `sudo tee < /dev/zero /dev/sda` **after** you've backed up everything) because it's the only way to get rid of low level malware - even you boot loader might be compromised.

(To be completely safe, you'd better reflash your motherboard BIOS as well because modern malware is capable of infecting UEFI BIOS).

Comment: Indeed, also the real kswapd0, being a kernel process, would use 0 VIRT/RES/SHR (because kernel doesn't account its own usage in kernel threads). @Harry please also take a look at SF's "generic" Q/A about compromised systems: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server/218011#218011

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov, I am using the azure machine : Its in cloud

Comment: @Harry Then simply abandon this instance and create a new one. It would be great if you found out how you'd been hacked because it's quite serious.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, the elk user has the root permission, So its not a malware then?

Comment: Your top output indicates you're **running malware**. The kswapd0 process is malware. I'm not sure why you're still asking questions.

Comment: In other words: the `kswapd0` process you're seeing is a piece of malware trying to look like a real kswapd0. But a real kswapd0 would have 0s in the VIRT, RES and SHR columns. That is how we know it's fake.

Comment: Probable malware's name: Outlaw. cryptomining, and also `tsm` is bruteforcing SSH: https://yoroi.company/research/outlaw-is-back-a-new-crypto-botnet-targets-european-organizations/ , https://www.oguzhantopgul.com/2020/06/outlaw-botnet-xmrig-miner-and-shellbot.html

Comment: (hum actually Outlaw is the "group" and their "product" is Shellbot)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks, But its an Azure machine in cloud, What is the way they can hack it?

Comment: @Harry There are multiple ways: 1) you are using insecure simple passwords 2) you're exposing incorrectly configured services to the internet 3) your instance hasn't been fully updated and is running insecure software stack 4) Your own PC has been  breached (which is the worst) and hackers simply use your passwords